# Regex to match number of digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a regex to match number of digits. The whole string can have atleast 6 digits and can have spaces and dashes.

for e.g.

```
123-45 6  valid
123456    valid
123-56    Invalid
```

Initially i wrote a regex that took care of minimum of 6 chars in the string. However, it did not work as it was counting the dashes and spaces as part of 6.

```
[\d\s-]{6,}
```

Tried

```
[\d]{6,}[\s-]
```

even this one is not working. Can you suggest how to fix this.

Another Attempt:

```
[[\d]{6,}[\s]*[-]*]
```

Comment: `(?:\d[\s\-]*){6}`

Comment: could you preprocess the string before you match?  the issue is that the `{6,} says 6 matches, not 6 digits, so the last one has 6 matches (with the dash) and the top one matches because of `123-45` not because of the 6 digits.

Comment: @Siguza that works !! Can you explain as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `String.replace` and `String.match` functions:

```
var isValid = function(str){
    var match = str.replace(/[\s-]/g, "").match(/^\d{6,}$/);
    return Boolean(match);
};

console.log(isValid("123-45 6"));  // true
console.log(isValid("12345678"));  // true
console.log(isValid("123-56"));    // false
console.log(isValid("123-567<"));  // false
```

Answer (score 4):

To check for the presence of at least 6 digits you can use `/(?:\d\D*){6,}/`.
If you also want it to only allow space and dash, you could adjust the pattern to `/^[ -]*(?:\d[ -]*){6,}$/`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either like this (accepts spaces and dashes at the end):

```
(\d[\s-]*){6,}
```

or like this (only dashes and spaces between digits):

```
(\d[\s-]*){5,}\d
```